# Navigate to different named outlet using a string variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have the following code:

```
class Example {
    .....
    exampleNavigate(namedOutlet:string, data: any) {
        const commands = [{
            outlets: {
                popup: [data.module, data.service, data.create]
            }
        }];
        let queryParams = {}
        queryParams['id'] = data.id;
        this.router.navigate(commands,  { queryParams } );
    }
    ...
}
```

Currently, I'm always navigating to the "popup" outlet. I can navigate to `namedOutlet` which is being passed through the `exampleNavigate` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I just need to replace `popup: [data.module, data.service, data.create]` to this `[outletName] : [data.module, data.service, data.create]` and it work fine.

Follows the full working example:

```
class Example {
    .....
    exampleNavigate(namedOutlet:string, data: any) {
        const commands = [{
            outlets: {
                [outletName]: [data.module, data.service, data.create]
            }
        }];
        let queryParams = {}
        queryParams['id'] = data.id;
        this.router.navigate(commands,  { queryParams } );
    }
    ...
}
```